# How to put all library (.so/.dll) files in a subdirectory?

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm using Pyinstaller for my cross-platform project and would like to "hide" all the library files (.so/.dll) inside a subdirectory so that the executable file is easier to find (right now the list of .so/.dll files is so long that we've had feedback from users who can't find it!)

**How can i modify my .spec files to put all .so/.dll files in a subdirectory?**

(I don't want to use `--one-file` because of some other reasons)

This is what my .spec file looks like for gnu/linux (file is similar for macos and windows):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

import os
cwd_str = os.getcwd()

a = Analysis(['mindfulness-at-the-computer.py'],
             pathex=[cwd_str],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./README.md', '.'), ('./LICENSE.txt', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

user_files_dir_str = "user_files"
a.datas += Tree('./' + user_files_dir_str, prefix=user_files_dir_str, excludes=['*.db'])
icons_dir_str = "icons"
a.datas += Tree('./' + icons_dir_str, prefix=icons_dir_str)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='mindfulness-at-the-computer',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='mindfulness-at-the-computer')
```

Grateful for help and with kind regards, Tord

Comment: Another reason for doing that, if you want to build a NuGet package, NuGet requires all assembly (dll, etc) to be in a lib subfolder. So bummed there's no answer to this question.

Comment: Do you found a solution?

Comment: @FabioDev Unfortunately no :(